# Checking for JDK os include directory... Cannot find jni_md.h in /bin

Tags: linux, tomcat9, java-21, openjdk-21, rhel9

I'm setting up tomcat 9 using java 21 and getting this error.

```
checking JAVA_HOME... /bin
  adding "-I/bin/include" to TCNATIVE_PRIV_INCLUDES
checking for JDK os include directory... Cannot find jni_md.h in /bin/
configure: error: You should retry --with-os-type=SUBDIR
```

Anyone seem this before having a missing file called jni_md.h on java 21 and tomcat 9.

I've tried some of the stack overflow answer I found but they all seem to be pointing to an old version of java.

I'm running this on RHEL-9

Comment: I see that file in `$JAVA_HOME/include/linux` - do you have it there?

Comment: I did a ```find / -type d -name "*include*"``` and got nothing back with java

Comment: Do you have a JDK installed?  What O/S are you compiling on?

Comment: ```drwxr-xr-x. 5 root root 68 Feb  9 13:23 java-21-openjdk-21.0.2.0.13-1.el9.x86_64
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 21 Feb  9 13:23 jre -> /etc/alternatives/jre
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 24 Feb  9 13:23 jre-21 -> /etc/alternatives/jre_21
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 32 Feb  9 13:23 jre-21-openjdk -> /etc/alternatives/jre_21_openjdk
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 40 Jan 12 15:06 jre-21-openjdk-21.0.2.0.13-1.el9.x86_64 -> java-21-openjdk-21.0.2.0.13-1.el9.x86_64
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 29 Feb  9 13:23 jre-openjdk -> /etc/alternatives/jre_openjdk```

Comment: ```/usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-21.0.2.0.13-1.el9.x86_64/``` 

yeah I have it here?

Comment: I'm running this on RHLE-9

Comment: @stdunbar was that helpful?

Comment: I spun up a VM of RHEL 9.3 and installed `java-21-openjdk-devel` on it.  In `/usr/lib/jvm/jre-21-openjdk-21.0.2.0.13-1.el9.x86_64/` I have an include directory that has the `linux` directory and your file.

Comment: It would be easier to read if you [edit] your question for new information, rather than adding comments.